# How to Crop Bitmap with RectangleF as bounds

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, bitmap

I am trying to crop a certain image with the RectangleF bounds I have. 
The following code works great in iOS (for my needs) using an UIImage as source:

```
//Crop a certain rectangle of your image
UIImage CropImage(UIImage srcImage, RectangleF rect)
{
   using (CGImage cr = srcImage.CGImage.WithImageInRect(rect))
   {
       UIImage cropped = UIImage.FromImage(cr);
       return cropped;
   }
}
```

I would like to have this same kind of function for Bitmaps in Android.

I tried the following, but not with the expected outcome:

```
//Crop a certain rectangle of your image
Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap srcImage, RectangleF rect)
{ 
    return Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(srcImage, (int)rect.Width,   
    (int)rect.Height, false);  
}
```

All ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// bmp - source bitmap
// x, y = origin for crop
// w, h = size of cropped image
return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp, x, y, w, h);
```